# Navigating OpenXML Document with XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, ms-office, openxml

Probably a very stupid question but I've been researching this for a bit and I'm probably just overlooking something very simple.

How exactly can I return en OpenXMLElementList with an XPath query?

Comment: Use the OpemXML SDK instead of XPath - that makes life a LOT easier.

Comment: Better yet, use LINQ to XML. Check out Eric White's work on parsing Open XML with it.